# Two SurfaceHolders in one Activity

Tags: android, media-player, rtsp, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I want to play one RTSP stream in a surfaceView while I prepare the other in a separate thread. However, the MediaPlayer does give an error when instantiating two SurfaceHolders:

`Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFErrResource`

Despite this, the video gets buffered, but when I switch to it, only audio is played. In the Android docs it is stated that this is a consequence of not calling setDisplay(SurfaceHolder) but this is what causes the error. 
Does anyone have any idea how I can make the video part of the stream show and how to avoid the error when calling setDisplay? Is this a platform limitation? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could put two separate `SurfaceView`s inside (for example) `FrameLayout`. Use these with two separate `MediaPlayer`s and show/hide (in parallel to stoping/starting video) `SurfaceView` you desire at given moment (using `android:visibility` set to `GONE` for example).